# Unable to align TextView above Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Coordinator Layout showing cardview, I wanted to show TextView above this coordinator layout, I tried putting Coordinator Layout inside Linear Layout just like how we do for Frame Layout, but that didn't work. Can someone help

[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:comfort="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="@color/eula_body_text_color"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="-12dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Image is no more accesible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="@color/eula_body_text_color"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:comfort="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="-12dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Main Problem is you want textview outside the coordinatorlayout but you are defining as child of that layout. So, you need to create a parent layout which have two childs i.e. 1. TextView and 2. CoordinatorLayout.

```
<LinearLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <CoordinatorLayout>
     all Views
   </CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion